# Absolutely positioning an INPUT element in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

i am having some  problem with `position: absolute` div. IE7 displays it next to the input but in normal browsers it is displayed under it. how can i fix it? 
I am using some third party javascript which i can not modify so I cant insert anything between `input` and `div`.

```
<div style="position: relative" id="header">qwe</div>
  <div style="position: relative">
    <table style="background: red; position: relative">     
      <tr>
         <td>      
            <input type="text" style="width:200px; " value="a date here" />        
            <div style="position:absolute; width: 300px; height: 300px; background: #eeeeee;"> 
              [a calendar here]       
            </div>        
         </td>  
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> 
         [text/inputs/buttons behind the calendar]
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

its just an example I made for this problem. i do have position: relative set on few elements in my code, fails with ie7 anyway. "under it" means its supposed to be calendar showing under that input after clicking it to let user pick some date easily.

edit: reworked example

edit: [problem solver - link removed] - click on the right "zapytanie i rezerwacja" and then "folwark zamkowy". you can find those calendar inputs in that form. `<a>` block containing calendar is added right after input from javascript.

Comment: i understand what you mean but ie7 compatibility is necessary in this project.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you *want* it to look like?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Without any "left" or "bottom" (or similar) declarations, the "position: absolute" does almost nothing as far as layout is concerned. Did you try simply removing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I still don't follow your code. I've no idea why you're doing is the way you are (why use a Table?), but you need to have `top:` and/or `left:` (or right or bottom) after your `absolute:position`.

For example: `style="position:absolute; top:5px; left: 5px;"`

Also, get rid of `float:left`. I've no idea what that's doing in there(!).

---

**Update update:** If you just want the text to appear behind the calendar, then you need to absolutely position your table.

Comment: its just an example I made for this problem. i do have position: relative set on few elements in my code, fails with ie7 anyway. "under it" means its supposed to be calendar showing under that input after clicking it to let user pick some date easily.

Comment: Could you post your actual code. IE7 isn't causing this problem, I'm guessing.

Comment: I think this short example shows everything. What exactly do you need?

Comment: @eyveer I've updated my answer. To be honest, it's still really unclear what you're trying to achieve. I'm sure it can be done, though, and that IE7 is not the problem (you just got lucky with the other browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `float:left;`?
Maybe the missing floating is the problem.
But IE7 is a problem itself.

Comment: yes i did. doesnt fix anything in ie7 and makes new problems in normal browsers.